# Kafka topic viewer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to debug some Kafka topics so I know if the consumer or producer is at fault here.

Is there a UI for Kafka where I can see what messages a topic contain?
A dumper would also be nice so I can search for stuff on my own.

Comment: [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) for the command line.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. See [help]

Comment: Gafka also a good free gui application isurujayakantha.github.io/gafka-releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll second Yoni Gibb's suggestion of the Landoop product. I also use it in development and find it very useful; although you may need to tweak a few settings around timeout and size in order to see all messages. Easy to install, just pull the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-topics-ui).

Kafkacat is useful too, but it's not quite as good for being able to monitor many topics at once and be left running.

Comment: Was not able to connect to Kafka using Landoop if port on kafka is different.
Used this one https://github.com/cloudhut/kowl - pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Landoop's Kafka Topics UI](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui), which is pretty good. You can see topic contents and information (e.g. number of partitions, configuration, etc) and also export topic contents.

Comment: Gafka  also a good free gui application
https://isurujayakantha.github.io/gafka-releases/